# Algorithm to return the possible combination batches of required materials

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem, example I need to build a sofa using 300 meters of leather.

my materials come in different batches.

```
10m
20m
30m
40m
40m
50m
100m
200m
300m
```

My goal is to find the best combination to would fit my requirement.

With the above batches, the possible good match will be

```
300m
200m + 100m
200m + 50m + 30m + 20m
200m + 40m + 40m + 10m
200m + 40m + 30m + 20m + 10m
No wastage for the above example
```

But if my batches are:
40m
100m
220m
250m

then there must be wastage, and my combinations will be

```
220 + 100 with 20m wastage, 
250 + 100 with 50m wastage  
220 + 250 with 170m wastage
```

Comment: Is there any significance to the number of batches being used (for instance, the less batches the better)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in `O(n)` time complexity. This answer assumes that the given batch is already sorted.

The idea is to iterate from both side until they meet or the sum of both the side become less than the required length and keeping track of the minimum of each valid index/indices.

Suppose the batch we have is

```
40m 100m 220m 250m
 ^             ^
```

We check if the sum of the both of them or either of them can individually make the required length.

i.e) 40m < 300m and 250m < 300m and 40m + 250m < 300m

So, we move the start position forward by 1

```
40m 100m 220m 250m
     ^         ^
```

Again 100m < 300m & 250m < 300m but 100m + 250m > 300m - Since this is a possibility and greater that what we need we mark the indices and the wastage associated with this indices and iterate the end position by 1

```
40m 100m 220m 250m
       ^  ^
```

Again, Individually none of them can make 300m but together they can make 300m with lesser wastage. So we updated the indices and the wastage and return as in the next iteration the start would become equal to the end.

Comment: Hi thebenman, your algorithm is definitely a good one. However, I've updated my 1st example, where there can be combinations of many batches to fulfill the requirement. In your case, only 2 batch be selected. So if there is a situation where no 2 batch can fulfill the requirement, it will never be fulfill.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution to this problem may not be the best or efficient algorithm, but at least it does return me a list of possible matches(I think).

First of all, I need to filter and sort the batches of material resource I have. pseudo code as follows:

```
func filter_sort_batches(product, batches)
    newlist = []
    product_keys = product.keys

    foreach batch in batches:
        score = 0

        if split doesn't contain a product_key, ignore batch

        if the split doesn't contain a product_key but also contain other keys that the product doesn't require, ignore batch

        for each key in batch:
            if product[key] >= batch[key]:
                score += (product[key] - batch[key])
            else:
                score += (batch[key] - product[key]) * product[key]

        put [score, batch] to newlist
    newlist.sort_by score, where the lowest score is the best
```

To return matches need 2 functions, the 
main function as follows:

```
func find_match(list, product)
    newlist = list.clone
    matches = Array.new
    find_match_recursive(newlist, product, matches, Array.new)
    result = matches.sort_by score, where the lowest score is the best
    print result
```

recursive function as follows:

```
func find_match_recursive(list, product, matches, group)
    return if list is empty

    newlist = list.clone
    tuple = newlist.shift
    batch = tuple.last
    new_group = group.clone
    new_group << batch

    if has_met_quantity(check_outsanding_materials(product, new_group)):
        grp_tuple = score_group(new_group, product)
        score = grp_tuple[0]
        if score less than 2x of the sum of product's values:
            add grp_tuple to matches

    else:
        # recurse to get the next batch and try to meet quantity check
        find_match_recursive(newlist, product, matches, new_group)

    #ignore the current recursion and skip to next batch in the list
    find_match_recursive(newlist, product, matches, group)
```

Other functions I have not include to the psuedo code:

```
score_group: computes the wastage for each material used.
check_outsanding_materials: calculate how much material is required after substracting the batches
has_met_quantity: check if the above for any materials qty has met or not.
```